# Efficient Method of Converting int to String in Java

Tags: java, performance

```
Integer.toString(int);
```

and

```
String.valueOf(int);
```

Which one among the above two methods is the efficient way of converting an int to String?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say which is more efficient, but the difference might be too small to care about.

Comment: Same as [Integer.toString(int i) vs String.valueOf(int i)
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i)., which also has profiling results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String.valueOf` calls `Integer.toString`, so I guess you could argue that `Integer.toString` is marginally more efficient.

EDIT: With a modern compiler the calls will be inlined so there should be no difference at all between the two. With an ancient compiler the difference should still be negligible.

Comment: Yeah, I use Integer.toString(int); but today I saw String.valueOf(int); in other developer's code. And I was wondering whats the difference between the two.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28int%29 for reference.

Comment: @Mudassir: In practice the difference will be completely negligible. The cost of a function call is extremely low, and in this case a decent compiler will probably optimise it away since `String.valueOf` is a one-line method that delegates to `Integer.toString`.

Comment: @cameron for which implementation ? OpenJDK ?

Comment: @Euphoria: I looked at the Sun Java 6 code, but @Mark's reference to OpenJDK has the same one-liner.

Comment: @Cameron - unless you run this on a really old JVM, the HotSpot JIT **will** inline the call, making the two calls' performance identical.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, I know. I mentioned that in my follow-up comment (albeit not as succinctly as you just put it). I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the String.valueOf() method was just provided for the purpose of flexibility, Since the purpose is closely related with String class(in fact for the conversion to String). While the (Integer/Float/etc).toString() method is the authentic method for the purpose of String conversion. You can refer them as slightly overloaded method.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it doesn't matter which method you use. But I think `Integer.toString(int);` is more efficient because, `String.toString(int);` is internally calling the same method.