# toString vs toString(parameter) vs valueOf(parameter) in java

Tags: java, string, casting, tostring

I am still confused what is the exact difference between this three methods

For example:

```
Double d = 19.23456;
System.out.println(d.toString());
System.out.println(Double.toString(d));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(d));
```

All the above methods print the value, but I would like to know more of a logical meaning and differences between these methods. Which method is suitable for which scenarios?

I have gone through the below link where the accepted answer states toString(parameter) and valueOf(parameter) are the same. Then what about `toString`? May be I am missing a significant point or something. If so please turn my attention towards it.

[Integer.toString(int i) vs String.valueOf(int i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i)

I have read the documentation but I couldn't make out the differences after reading it.

According to the official docs:

**toString**

```
 Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object.
 Subclasses are encouraged to override this method and provide an implementation that takes into account the object's type and data. 
The default implementation is equivalent to the following expression: 

           getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

**toString(parameter)**

```
Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of the specified double value
```

**valueOf(parameter)**

```
Converts the specified object to its string representation. If the object is null return the string "null", otherwise use toString() to get the string representation.
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

Well I am satisfied by both the answers provided by Eran and zapl. Each of the answers clears the concepts of this method within a specific perspective. For the sake of accepting an answer I would be accepting one. Thank You for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the exact difference between this three methods?

Pretty much none.

via JDK8's [String.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java)

When you have a primitive `double` it can't be `null` and is directly forwarded to `Double`.

```
3125  public static String valueOf(double d) {
3126      return Double.toString(d);
3127  }
```

When you have a boxed `Double` value that can be `null`, this either prints "null" or forwards to the objects `toString()` method.

```
2978  public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
2979      return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
2980  }
```

JDK 8's [Double.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Double.java)

To avoid code duplication this simply forwards the internal value to the static method

```
643  public String toString() {
644      return toString(value);
645  }
```

And the static method does the "actual work" by delegating to some "internal" implementation.

```
203  public static String toString(double d) {
204      return FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString(d);
205  }
```

Regardless of what you do. If there is a value to print it will be `Double#toString(double d)` that does the job. The same applies to `Integer`, ..

Using `String.valueOf(Object)` is also what happens when you do `println("Value is: " + value)`. It prints `"null"` instead of trying to call the `toString` method on a non existing object.

Comment: You mean when I am using valueOf(parameter) or toString, toString(parameter) method is called for both.. So if I am aware of the parameter type.. I should go for toString(parameter) assuming that would be more direct implementation??

Comment: @pooh1527 Most of the time, you would simply concatenate via `"stuff" + value` and it does the right thing for you. I would consider that the best because it's the simplest approach. When you need an explicit `String` value, I'd suggest using `String.valueOf(value)` because it does the right thing with `null` too and you don't have to hardcode a specific class and `toString(value)` method. How exactly the implementation looks should not concern you, so you should not start using `toString(param)` just because it is more direct - maybe thats the case in this Java version only.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `Integer.toString()` and `Integer.toString(int)` is that the latter is a static method, and therefore can be called for a primitive variable. The former is an instance method, and can only be called on a reference type.

`String.valueOf(Object)` is different than the `toString()` instance methods, since `String.valueOf(null)` would return "null", while `null.toString()` would throw a `NullPointerException`.
`Integer.toString(int)` will also throw a `NullPointerException` when pass a null `Integer` reference, since the attempt to unbox that `Integer` would result in that exception.

Therefore, if you have an `Integer i` variable, `String.valueOf(i)` will behave differently than `i.toString()` and `Integer.toString(i)` when `i` is `null`.

Comment: `Integer.toString(i)` doesn't (or at least *shouldn't*) autobox `i` to a primitive. It *should* give a compilation error

Comment: @blgt I just tried `Integer i= null;String s = Integer.toString(i);` and got `NullPointerException`. What are you basing your claim on?

Comment: @blgt Based on the [JLS 5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), `Method invocation contexts allow ... an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion`.

Comment: @Eran -- Thank you for clearing much of my confusion.. so I can use toString and valueOf when I am working with objects and primitive types both? But toString(parameter) is only for primitive types.. Also both toString methods will throw nullpointer exception while valueOf won't and just return string representation of null? Have I understood it correctly??

Comment: @pooh1527 Almost. You got it mixed up. `toString()` is only for objects. toString(parameter) can be used for both objects and primitives (since objects can be unboxed into primitives).

Comment: @Eran -- and what about custom objects?? objects of my custom class?

Comment: @pooh1527 In your own classes it's up to you whether to override toString() or not.

Comment: @Eran You're right, no error and no warning. I'm apparently basing my claim on misremembering stuff