# How to convert int to String?

Tags: java

how can i convert int to String so that i can getparameter?

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/searchUsers")
public String searchUsers(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap map, 
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
        @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size) {
    String searchId = request.getParameter("userId");

    String searchProductName = request.getParameter("productName");
    String searchQuantity = request.getParameter("quantity");
    String searchStock = request.getParameter("stock");
    String searchDate = request.getParameter("date");


    Product searchProduct = new Product();
    searchProduct.setPid(searchId);
    searchProduct.setPname(searchProductName);
    searchProduct.setPquantity(searchQuantity);
    searchProduct.setPstock(searchStock);
    searchProduct.setPdate(searchDate);
```

MyClass

```
private int id;

@Column(name="p_name")
private String pname;

@Column(name="p_quantity")
private String pquantity;
```

as you can see in my class i have int id use for autoincrement in my db.
how can i convert my Id to String without changing String Id in my class so that i can request.getParameter it in my controller??

as you can see in my controller
String searchId 
It can not store in my database because it is set to String.

so how can i convert my int Id to String?can someone help me. thanks in advance

Comment: which `id` do you want to convert from int to String?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4105331/3898076

Comment: aw okey ill try it later

Comment: You can define another setter in your class which takes String as input and convert it to int and set the value of id. Same way create a getter which converts int into String (Integer.toString(id)) and return it.

Comment: i thought i can use int id=request.getParameter("userId"); im wrong ...

Comment: You can not change the predefined methods such as request.getParameter("userId"), you need to caste the result such as `Integer.parseInt("2");` (Need to handle the exceptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:**
You can caste the String in your controller

```
String searchId = request.getParameter("userId");
int id = Integer.parseInt(searchId); //Null check and NumberFormatException to be handled.
searchProduct.setPid(id);
```

**Approach 2:**
You create methods in your entity class which takes String as input.

```
private int id;

/*Default getter setter*/
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/*String based getter setter*/
public String getIdStr() {
    return Integer.toString(id);
}
public void setId(String id) throws NumberFormatException {
    this.id = Integer.parseInt(id); // Null check to be added 
}
```

Use it in your controller.

```
searchProduct.setId(searchId);  //searchId is String
```

Comment: still no luck sir.                                                                                         java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: You can add null check before setting the value in setter method.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to use the int as a String

```
String s = String.valueOf(id);
```

is what you want

[`String.valueOf(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) Returns the string representation of the int argument.

Answer (score 0):

From top, there are three replies.

1st, `String s = String.valueOf(int)`. This is correct.

2nd, `String z = "" + myInt`. This is workable but take more memory. (Not a good practice)

3rd, `return Integer.toString(id);` Better use String.valueOf instead.

See 
[Java - Convert integer to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string)

[Integer.toString(int i) vs String.valueOf(int i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i)

Thank you.