# Incompatible type error java.lang.integer in base adapter

Tags: android

I am very new to android,I am trying to display images in grid view ,in my base adapter i am getting error ,Incompatible Type java.lang.integer in my get Item method any one help me please how to resolve my issue,

here my adapter code

```
private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
private Activity activity;

public GalleryAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Integer> listFlag) {
    super();

    this.listFlag = listFlag;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listFlag.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listFlag.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView imgViewFlag;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gallery_viewlayout, null);

        view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);

        convertView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
    view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is supposed to return String but it is returning Integer.
This should fix the issue:

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return Integer.toString(listFlag.get(position));
}
```

Comment: why not String.valueOf() ??

Comment: @VivekMishra it's the same thing choose whichever you prefer. Did this not solve your problem?

Comment: I wanted to know if they are different or same

Comment: @VivekMishra see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i

Comment: thanq@IllegalArgument