# Cannot get String Value from Array list: Getting only [Ljava.lang.string @

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm parsing `Outlook SCV` file to `ArrayList`.
Then i want to get `String` values of the `Array` list i'm getting.

**Here is the code:**

```
 if(arr != null){
        try{
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
           oneRow = new ArrayList();
            oneRow.add(arr.get(i));
                for (int j = 0; j < oneRow.size(); j++) {

                StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
                    strBuild.append(String.valueOf(oneRow.get(j).toString()));
```

**Here is the `ArrayList`:**
[image: ArrayList]

No matter what i tried, i can't get the `String` Value.
What i get is : [Ljava.lang.string @....

Here is the Class that makes the `ArrayList` which getting the `CSV` file and building the `ArrayList`:

```
public class ReadingCSV {


InputStream inputStream;

public ReadingCSV(InputStream inputStream){
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}

public List read(){
    ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    try {
        String csvLine;
        while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
            resultList.add(row);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: "+e);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of: `String.valueOf(oneRow.get(j).toString())` ??

Comment: There is no purpose, i just trying to get the String value of ArrayList on [j] position.

Comment: Have you tried simply casting to String?

Comment: put the code to know exactly what kind of object this `arr` ? then only we will able to write Code for you

Comment: I have something to say for all of these "nice" people who gave my question negatives feedback.
It is very sad, because I think that the purpose of stackoverflow is to help people, and how a person will learn if he gets a negative feedback right away?!
Instead of clicking that down arrow, maybe you should try to help.

Many many Thanks for those, who really tried to help me.

Comment: Relax. Breathe slowly. Take a step outside... We've all been in your situation... I know that StackOverflow can feel like a very hostile place, especially if you're new here. Posting a complaint about this as an answer or comment is not the way to go, though. If you have any questions / remarks on the rules here at StackOverflow or the behavior of certain users, the proper procedure is to address them @ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** :- This Code is compiled and run using `jdk V1.8`

try this out this is a working code. you can Manipulate as per your need.

```
public List<String> read(){
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList(); //A Type-Safety (String) ArrayList
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    try {
        String csvLine;
        while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = csvLine.split(","); //row is String Array Object
            for(String eachWord : row) //Iterate each String from the array
            resultList.add(eachWord);  // add String to the Type-Safe ArrayList.
        }
    }catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
}
finally {
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: "+e);
    }
}
return resultList;
   }
  }
```

update Your another code with this

```
if(arr != null){
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
           ArrayList<String> oneRow = new ArrayList();
            oneRow.add(arr.get(i));
                for (int j = 0; j < oneRow.size(); j++) {
                    strBuild.append(oneRow.get(j));
                }
    }
    System.out.println(strBuild.toString());
}
```

> This Code is perfectly Working. You may try it by your own. If any issue you may put a comment .

Comment: Vikrant Kashyap, 
Thank you so much, You are a genius.
3 days i'm trying to make it work.
Unfortunately i can't give this answer a positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you double convert to String this:

strBuild.append(String.valueOf(oneRow.get(j).toString()));

I think,this is helps you:
[Help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i)