# Andorid Java String - Which is better? "" +, toString(), String.valueOf()?

Tags: java, android, string

What is the difference between these in Android / Java?
Which is more efficient and what tool did you use to find the differences?

```
String text = input.getText().toString();

String text = String.valueOf(input.getText());

String text = input.getText() + "";
```

assuming input is not null...

**EDIT**: `input.getText()` returns an [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer.toString(int i) vs String.valueOf(int i)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i)

Comment: @Durgpal Singh - that's a completely different question

Comment: What type does input.getText() return?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis an Editable

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050845/why-we-use-string-message-edittext-gettext-tostring-after-using-edittext-e

Comment: @DurgpalSingh again, that's not related at all to this question...

Comment: i think you didn't read all the answers.

Comment: @DurgpalSingh i'm not going to read all the answers when the question is irrelevant because the answers will also be irrelevant.

Comment: that's not right always. keep remember.

Comment: @DurgpalSingh thank you, i will keep remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely `toString()`.
It clearly states what you want, i.e. to get the `String` of the returned [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html).

[`getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) cannot return null, so the null safety of `String.valueOf()` is not needed, and `String.valueOf()` simply turns around and calls `toString()`, so why not just call it directly, since that is shorter?

`input.getText() + ""` is just lazy and obscure and generates bad code. Sure, JIT may eliminate it, but it's still a hack. *(My opinion anyway)*

Comment: That's a better answer.  I've always used .toString() but we've been outsourcing and they are all using "" + input.getText() and i've been wondering if it's quicker.  I found another post that said it's slower that way, so it seems like toString() is the most efficient and, in my view, elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` is the best method to call. 
`text+""` is the dirty way of coding.