# Performance difference between Integer.toString() and String.valueOf()?

Tags: java, string, integer

I have an integer let say, `int a = 123;`

Now, I can convert it to String using below two ways:

```
1. Integer.toString(a)
2. String.valueOf(a)
```

I want to know, if there is any performance difference between the above two ways, let say when we are doing this for 10k integers or more and if yes then why?

Comment: Test it using [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer.toString(int i) vs String.valueOf(int i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i)

Answer (score 5):

`String.valueOf(int)` internally calls the `Integer.toString(int)`. So there will not be any performance difference. Or theoretically Integer.toString should be better as 1 less call.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the source for both method as of JDK 8

This is the source for `Intger.toString()`

```
 public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

And this is the source for `String.valueOf(int)`

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

As you can see there will be barely any difference in the performance , `Integer.toString()` is called in both  cases

But I you have to choose one then the answer is `Integer.toString()` because that way i can reduce the overhead of calling `String.valueOf(int)`  it will be barely anything , but as you may know a method call involves many things like putting method call on stack , saving state and control return position , then poping it off the stack , that all will be avoided, but still computers are too fast so it doesn't count

Answer (score 1):

The performance should be nearly identical because `String.valueOf(a)` is defined as follows:

```java
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

It also goes to reason that `Integer.toString` would be faster since it can skip `String.valueOf` on the call stack, but I don't know if the difference is enough to notice in practice.

Unfortunately java does not normally inline function calls so at a minimum it will need to spend extra time loading the function, but after the first call the CPU cache would likely make the redirect nearly unnoticeable.

**Edit**: You can find this on your own by using *go to definition* in your IDE. I was able to get this code snippit by selecting the function call and pressing **Ctrl + B** in Intellij Idea.

Comment: Java Virtual Machines usually perform some form of JIT, which can inline methods like this.

Comment: "Java does not normally inline function calls": false.