# Filter an object list based on Integerlist

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class like

```
class Employee
  String id
  String name
```

I want to filter out the list of employees based on the list of deptId which is an integer list

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee("1","Ally");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("2","Billy");
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(emp1,emp2);
ArrayList<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(2);
```

What I have written is

```
List<Employee> filteredList = employeeList.stream()
  .filter(employee -> ids.contains(employee.getId()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But as an output I get an empty array.

Comment: That is because your employee id is a `String` rather than an `int`.

Comment: Also, I suggest to transform your `ids` list into a `Set`. The widely-used `HashSet` implementation of the `Set` interface has a much better lookup time complexity (*O(1)* instead of *O(n)*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change `subscription` to `employee`.

Either change your ID list to a list of `Strings` and populate accordingly or do something like this:

```
List<Employee> filteredList;
filteredList = employeeList.stream()
     .filter(employee -> ids.contains(Integer.parseInt(employee.getId())))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Other options include changing your `Employee` class to use an `int` as an id.

Comment: `Integer.toString(employee.getId())` or `String.valueOf(employee.getId())`? That's [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i).

Comment: Thanks!  I must still be asleep as I just realized that the lambda in the filter is not correct.  `subscription` should be `employee`