# How to use stream to get id from array of object in List?

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose i have list of objects in java which contain ids and name , how can i pick only id and save it into another list

details[{id:1,name:brown},{id:2,white},{id:3,name:black}]

I want is all the ids into the new List.

what i tried is

```
List<String> ids = details.stream().filter(item -> item.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This throws syntax error near item.getId()

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64877285/filter-an-object-list-based-on-integerlist

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `.filter`, you need to use `.map`.

To make your code a bit cleaner, you can replace `item -> item.getId()` with a method reference: `Item::getId`.

This would be the end result:

```
List<String> ids = details.stream()
        .map(Item::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: i really didn't get this

Comment: The .map method is used for transforming objects. That's what you need, since you're transforming Item objects to Strings (the id). The method reference is just a way to express the lambda expression in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

The sample works for you,

```
        Employee emp1 = new Employee(1,"Ally");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(2,"Billy");
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(emp1,emp2));

        List<Integer> collect = employeeList.stream()
                                            .map(Employee::getId)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("collect = " + collect);
```